# Can I give the horizontal slider css3 border radius?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a JQUI slider here, sized with percentages. I can use the border radius to round the slider, but the range highlight doesn't inherit this rounding:

http://jsfiddle.net/BjeNx/20/

If I update the class ".ui-widget-head" like this:

```
.ui-widget-header {
    border-radius: 90px;
}
```

We get somewhere:
http://jsfiddle.net/BjeNx/21/

But then, as the slider handle approaches the minimum value, the rounding gradually disappears!

[This](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9024#comment:2) suggests it can be done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slider range is scaling like it should.

The problem is that your slider range is overflowing outside of its parent div. To fix this, you could apply `overflow:hidden` to its parent, `.ui-slider-horizontal`.

[Fiddle with Overflow](http://jsfiddle.net/BjeNx/22/)

This unfortunately prevents the slider handle from overflowing as well.

The easiest way to achieve what you are trying to do is to set a `min-width` on the slider range that will stop it from scaling at a certain percentage. This percentage would be the point at which it starts overflowing.

[Fiddle with Min-Height](http://jsfiddle.net/BjeNx/24/)

This will only work if your slider handle is hiding the actual range behind it.

CSS:

```
.ui-slider-range-min {
    min-width: 14%;
}
```

Comment: The min-height's definitely the way to go here, thanks.

This fiddle stops rounding on the right side of the range bar, so it looks pretty much perfect :) :

 http://jsfiddle.net/BjeNx/25/